# override PrincipalPermissionAttribute SecurityAction.Demand method

Tags: asp.net, security

how can I override PrincipalPermissionAttribute SecurityAction.Demand method?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Both `PrincipalPermission` and `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` are sealed classes.